# Web application shortcuts on mobile devices

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications, windows-phone-7, shortcut

I need to create application shortcuts on 3 different mobile environments, WP7, Android and iPhone (iOS).

Currently I don't have any of these devices so I can't test if its possible.

- target would be some web application.

Is it possible to create shortcuts on "desktop" in these environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes for all of the platforms you mention.